# Scala-Spark: Filter DataFrame Performance and Optimization

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

What I'm trying to achieve is fairly simple: I want to check all IDs (uuid's) if they experience a certain "status" (behavioral status). If they do, then return to me all the records associated with that ID. For example, if one of the ID's below has a status of "three" I want to keep all those records associated with that ID. So far I can achieve this with the following two ways:

```
// first method
val dfList = df.filter($"status" === "three").select($"id").distinct.map(_.getString(0)).collect.toList
val dfTransformedOne = df.filter($"id".isin(dfList:_*))

// second method
val dfIds = df.filter($"status" === "three").select($"id").distinct
val dfTransformedTwo = df.join(broadcast(dfIds), Seq("id"))
```

The above two methods work fine with the sample data I'm working with, however I'm running into some performance issues when I start increasing the amount of data to process because I could have millions to hundreds of millions of IDs that I need to filter for. Is there a more efficient way to do the above or should it just be a case of bumping up the hardware I'm using?

Below is the example data and expected output.

```
val df = Seq(
  ("1234", "one"), 
  ("1234", "two"), 
  ("1234", "three"), 
  ("234", "one"), 
  ("234", "one"), 
  ("234", "two")
  ).toDF("id", "status")

df.show
+----+------+
|  id|status|
+----+------+
|1234|   one|
|1234|   two|
|1234| three|
| 234|   one|
| 234|   one|
| 234|   two|
+----+------+

dfTransformed.show()
+----+------+
|  id|status|
+----+------+
|1234|   one|
|1234|   two|
|1234| three|
+----+------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping and aggregating before filtering will introduce a shuffle, while eliminating the need to collect the large list to the driver. Whether it's faster is dependent on your data distribution, cluster size, and network connectivity. It is probably worth a test though:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("1234", "one"), 
  ("1234", "two"), 
  ("1234", "three"), 
  ("234", "one"), 
  ("234", "one"), 
  ("234", "two")
  ).toDF("id", "status")

df.groupBy("id")
  .agg(collect_list("status").as("statuses"))
  .filter(array_contains($"statuses", "three"))
  .withColumn("status", explode($"statuses"))
  .select("id", "status")
  .show(false)
```

Gives the intended result:

```
+----+------+
|id  |status|
+----+------+
|1234|one   |
|1234|two   |
|1234|three |
+----+------+
```